# Google OAuth: can't get access token

Tags: php, oauth, google-oauth

I'm just starting with google OAuth using the PHP Client Library. I'm having trouble getting the example from the Google APIs site working. [Google's Example](https://developers.google.com/api-client-library/php/auth/web-app#exchange-authorization-code)

When i try to exchange the authorization code for a token, it just returns `NULL`.  No errors or exceptions.

I thought maybe it was a problem with my `client_secret.json`, but I don't know what to look for.

Here's my full code:

```
$client = new \Google_Client();
$client->setAuthConfig('client_secret.json');
$client->setRedirectUri('http://localhost/test.php');
$client->setAccessType('offline');
$client->addScope(\Google_Service_Gmail::MAIL_GOOGLE_COM);

if (! isset($request->code)) {
    return redirect($client->createAuthUrl());
} else {
    $client->authenticate($request->code);
    $token = $client->getAccessToken(); // <- returns NULL, but no execeptions or errors
    dd($token);
    return redirect('https://www.googleapis.com/oauth2/v3/tokeninfo?id_token=' . $token);
}
```